# de serializing data into a model is passing null values into my output C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a method that is reading a serialized string from my database and then attempting to de serialize it while passing it into my model, for the purposes of this, i will hard code the data in, it is giving me the same result both ways

```
const string serialized =
                "{\"Id:\": 1,\"Title:\":\"Mr\" ,\"Name:\":\"Someone Random\",\"Dob:\":\"2016-02-20 00:00:00.000\",\"Address:\":\"Just around the corner\",\"Email:\":\"somone.random@email.com\",\"Telephone:\":\"000022233441\",\"Mobile:\":\"079999999\"}";

            using (var sr = new StringReader(serialized))
            {
                using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    var js = new JsonSerializer();
                    var model = js.Deserialize<DataWrapper>(jr);
                    return model;
                }
            }
```

My DataWrapper model looks like so

```
public class DataWrapper
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

Now no matter if I am hard coding the data in or returning it from the database, it always returns a blank Model

at the point where i am trying to Deserialize the data into my model, the data is actually there(in the jr) but it seems it is being lost at the same time, so when i return my model, it is always a blank instance of my model

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your JSON string, you've added a ':' at the end of your property names. Pretty-printed, your JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Id:": 1,
    "Title:": "Mr",
    etc.
}
```

To automatically map to your properties, remove the trailing colon, i.e.:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Mr",
    etc.
}
```

Comment: Another way to map the properties automatically would be to modify the `DataWrapper` class to include a `JsonProperty` attribute.  Ex: `[JsonProperty("Id:")]` above the `Id` property.

Comment: @codran thanks, it's always stuff like this that catches me out

Answer (score 0):

You wrote ":" character at the end of properties. Remove them and let them to be like that:

```
"{\"Id\":2,\"Title\":\"aaa\",\"Name\":null,\"Dob\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"Address\":\"sdfsd\",\"Email\":null,\"Telephone\":null,\"Mobile\":null}";
```